# how to compile glblendequation in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, blending

how to compile glBlendEquation() in visual studio 2010?
it say:
error C3861: 'glBlendEquation': identifier not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that glBlendEquation is missing from the gl.h header that is provided by Microsoft. You should use [Glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to get it to work.